# TFS - Is there a way to see which TestCase work items are not in any Test Plans?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-test-manager

We'd like to be able to see which new Test Cases work items have yet to be associated with a Test Plan/Test Suite.
I figure that if we can get this query working in TFS in Visual Studio, then we can save it off and the Testing folks can load that query in Test Manager and see which items still need to be added to plans.

Comment: I think there is not any possibility to achieve that using a work item query.
I currently need something similar: I want to know which Test Plan/Test Suite a particular Test Case is associated with.
So I'm going to create a report. To my knowledge it is the only way to achieve that (except implementing a small console application using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client API).

Comment: That's too bad.  I'm digging around the Tfs_Warehouse right now to see if I can find the link between the DimWorkItem and the DimTestSuite.  Hopefully something comes up.  It would be best if I could get to this info from Analysis Services so that I could just keep an Excel report posted to the sharepoint site.  We'll see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Related Link Count=0**
I think it can help you.